# ES5 javascript Filter JSON object based on array multiple key object

Tags: json, filter, ecmascript-5

With Javascript ES5, return JSON object based on tags array.
Each object have tags array and I am trying to return only the object that matches all of the tags.name.

For example, if the filter condition based on all tags name (tags[0].name , tags[1].name , tags[2].name ) is ['energy', 'video'], the return object should have tags name containing both energy and video (it can still have other tags like featured)

```
tags: [
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Featured',
          name: 'featured'
        },
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Video',
          name: 'video'
        },
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Energy',
          name: 'energy'
        }
      ]
```

Using Array.prototype.filter(), I was able to return object that match single value -> tags[0].name
However, I need to return object based on all the tags name -> tags[0].name , tags[1].name , tags[2].name

I tried using Array.prototype.map() to combine all tags name to an array -> Array(3) [ "featured", "video", "energy" ]

And tried with Array.prototype.filter() to return object based on the new tag array but it doesn't return any object but Array []

Kindly see testing code at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjLKBR

I expect the output return object of

```
{
      title: 'Video Energy Featured',
      tags: [
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Featured',
          name: 'featured'
        },
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Video',
          name: 'video'
        },
        {
          localizedTitle: null,
          title: 'Energy',
          name: 'energy'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you want the code to work. You want to filter the list to just one element that matches all the `tags` on an array, or that matches any of the `tags` on an array? Could you clarify the interface you are trying to implement?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Filter to return object that match all the tags. For example, if the filter condition based on all tags name (tags[0].name , tags[1].name , tags[2].name ) is ['energy', 'video'], the return object should have tags name containing both energy and video (it can still have other tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track using `filter`. Here is my take on your problem.

```
function filterItems(items, tags) {
  return items.filter(function(item) {
    var itemTags = item.tags.map(function (tag) { return tag.name; });
    return tags.every(function(tag) { return itemTags.indexOf(tag) > -1  });
  })
}
```

You call it with the items to filter and the list of `tags`. It returns the filtered list.

It is not the most optimal code, but it should do the work.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the solution.